# Drawing the graph of the logarithm of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a function, which involves taking the logarithm of another function, over the domain (0,1).

The graph is not smooth as it nears 0, as you can see in the image below, which it produces. In fact, it is not well-behaved quite a long way away from 0. But it appears well around 1.

How can I produce a graph that appears smooth over the whole domain?

**Code v1**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [xmin=0,xmax=1,xtick={0,1},ymin=0,ymax=0.12,ytick={0}]
    \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=100]{(1/2)*((1 - x)/x)*((ln((1 + x)/(1-x))/x) - 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output v1**

[image: graph]

**UPDATE:**

Rearranging the expression to make the arguments in ln() simpler seems to help `ln((1+x)/(1-x)) = ln(1+x)-ln(1-x)`. I also specified `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` as specified by KersouMan, but that did not help me much, as you can see. I also added `restrict y to domain={0:0.12}` to get rid of some big spikes. Finally, I thought I would give it a break and remove values close to 0 from the domain, instead using `domain=0:1`, but I do not want to do that, really I want pgfplots to graph this smoothly to (0,0).

Any more ideas?

**Code v2:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [xmin=0,xmax=1,xtick={0,1},ymin=0,ymax=0.12,ytick={0}]
    \addplot[domain=0.03:1,samples=100,restrict y to domain={0:0.12}]{(1/2)*((1 - x)/x)*( (ln(1 + x) - ln(1 - x))/x - 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output v2**

[image]

**Specific replies:**

Re: KersouMan - Unfortunately, that did not help me, I wonder how it helped you.

Re: Jasper Habicht - It is a smooth function that rises from y=0 when x=0 and tends back to y=0 when x=1. Yes, I also believe the issue is that pgfplots is having issues near 0 due to the function getting complicated.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an image how you want the plot to look like or double check whether the formula for it is right? It seems that the curve becomes quite complicated near zero which you can see if you increase the value for `samples`. I am unsure whether this curve is really what you're expecting.

Comment: Wouldn't know why, but adding a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` and increasing the number of `samples` gave me a correct result

Comment: Maybe the compatibility setting did not work because your `pgfplots` package is not up to date (unlikely since requiring a version ahead of what you have installed throws an error). Checking different versions, I have a correct result starting with `compat=1.12`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had updated the package, but it did not help. I also tried with all versions between `compat=1.12` and `compat=1.18`. For my purposes taking an approximate function for the domain near 0, as suggested by Juan, is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround: use the Taylor polynomial for the logarithmic part:

```
\documentclass[border=1.618]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,xtick={0,1},ymin=0,ymax=0.12,ytick={0}]
  \addplot[domain=0.4:1,samples=100] {(1/2)*((1 - x)/x)*( (ln(1 + x) - ln(1 - x))/x - 2)};
  \addplot[red,domain=0.0001:0.4,samples=41]{(1 - x)*(x/3 + x^3/5 + x^5/7 + x^7/9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this still gives visible jitter in the non-Taylor-polynomial part (look slightly left of the extremum).

Comment: @Skillmon, you're right it was only a workaround, and it probably would look passable depending on the size. But your answer is better (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be to use `xfp`/`l3fp` instead of the `pgf`-FPU. The following does so with the help of the `pgfmath-xfp` package to define your function. However, `myplot(0)` would try to divide by zero, so results in an error, the following starts the domain at `0.001` for that reason (it would also err for `myplot(1)` but that is never evaluated for the following domain).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfmath-xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [xmin=0,xmax=1,xtick={0,1},ymin=0,ymax=0.12,ytick={0}]
    % locally define the function myplot
    \pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{myplot}{1}{0.5 * ((1 - (#1))/(#1)) * ((ln((1+#1)/(1-(#1)))/(#1)) - 2)}
    \addplot[domain=0.001:1,samples=100]{myplot(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Cool that there is now a pgfmath-xfp package!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner "now" :) I wrote it more than 2 years ago.